# How to manage Modbus RS485 connection from a python script?

Tags: python, modbus, rs485

I need to control an external device from a python script, the device is already provided with an interface built in c# as dll file and the communication protocol is Modbus RS485 which i have no experience in.
I'm using Pythonnet to import the library and use the provided dll functions.
when I execute commands without pauses between them the device act strangly. i think the problem is that the device need time to recieve and execute the commands so i thought of creating a buffer like this:

```
class Buffer():

    def init(self):
        self.buffer = []

    def add_to_buffer(self, command):
        self.buffer.append(command)

    def execute(self):
        for command in self.buffer:
           time.sleep(some_time)
           print("executeing", command)
```

however I want to know if there is a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: I would go with pymodbus https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: A  common test in serial world is a loopback test, you need to wire tx and rx pins http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3450/en/ then you should read what you write, this can be used to check if what you're writing is what you expect to be